# How can I sort a list by the decimals only?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7, floating-point

I'd like to sort a list of numbers by the decimal numbers, regardless of the number to the left of the decimal point. For example, if:

```
some_list = [5.43, 12.01, 10.23, 3.33]
```

then the sorted list should be:

```
some_list_sorted = [12.01, 10.23, 3.33, 5.43]
```

Can that be done ?

Comment: No, it's impossible. Just kidding, of course it's possible. This is software, nothing is impossible. What have you tried? What code have you written so far? If nothing, then attempt something and come back when you have a question more constructive than "write me code that does X", because nobody here is willing to do your (home)work for free.

Comment: Yes, it can be done :)

Comment: It can be done in one line...

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: Woa, what's with all the downvotes? I googled for a solution and couldn't find anything, didn't know how to attack it myself so I posted a question.... what's wrong with that? :(

Comment: @user3477950 So not my work or homework. I honestly didn't know how to begin to attack it.

Comment: Seems a reasonable question to me...  Voting to reopen.

Comment: @MarkDickinson who knows how many downvotes I'll get if it's reopened :) Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a custom sort key, taking the decimal portion. You could use [`math.modf()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.modf) for splitting the float values in to a decimal and integer parts:

```
import math

sorted(some_list, key=lambda f: math.modf(f))
```

or use `% 1` to achieve the same:

```
sorted(some_list, key=lambda f: f % 1)
```

These differ in how they handle ties; the `% 1` ignores the integer part in that case and leaves the numbers in original (relative) order, while the `math.modf()` option will sort lower integer parts before higher.

`math.modf()` also preserves the sign, while modulus 1 ignores it:

```
>>> math.modf(-12.01)
(-0.009999999999999787, -12.0)
>>> -12.01 % 1
0.9900000000000002
```

Pick the one that fits your use case.

Demo:

```
>>> import math
>>> some_list = [5.43, 12.01, 10.23, 3.33]
>>> sorted(some_list, key=lambda f: math.modf(f))
[12.01, 10.23, 3.33, 5.43]
>>> sorted(some_list, key=lambda f: f % 1)
[12.01, 10.23, 3.33, 5.43]
```

Comment: @user667648: I was thinking the OP might want to use the integer portion still in case of ties.

Comment: Too kind, too kind... :D +1

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for this. I appreciate your help. I'd suggest one edit - "while the math.modf() option will sort lower decimals before higher." ==> write integers instead of decimals. That what it does to my understanding (and testing).

Comment: The two options also differ significantly in their handling of negative numbers ...

Comment: @Optimesh: ah, yes, indeed. Corrected.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: that is indeed an important distinction.